# LG Won't Charge

Tags: battery, charging

My LG was at 1% battery yesterday so I let it charge for an hour or so but when I came back I noticed that it wouldn't even turn on without turning right back off. It would only turn on to show a "0% battery" screen.

I tried another charger and the LG had the same issue; it just wouldn't stay on. However, this time, I did notice that once or twice it would flash the "charging" screen for a split second.

I let the phone sit overnight while connected to the charger and when I woke up it appears that at least some charge trickled into the device; it is able to turn on and reach the lock screen but not without immediately shutting off because of a low battery.

What could be wrong? What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

The two most likely causes:

1. The battery could be dead. Lithium-ion batteries (as well as other types of rechargeable batteries) wear down over time. Even sitting on a shelf they eventually decay, but they decay faster the more you use them, and the more they're exposed to extreme heat, cold, and humidity.
2. The socket on the phone has a loose connection. Jiggle the plug, or try applying light pressure in various directions.

If the battery is old (>2 years) or battery life has been getting shorter recently, it's probably the first one. The second one is more likely if the battery is fairly new or battery life hasn't noticeably decreased from when it was new and it just suddenly stopped charging, or if you notice the charge indicator flashing on the screen and disappearing while you're jiggling the plug.

You didn't specify what model you have, but most LG phones have replaceable batteries. Cell phone batteries are dirt cheap, so if you buy a replacement and it turns out to be a problem with the circuitry, you won't have wasted much money. You should be able to get a new one at Amazon or eBay for just a few bucks.

Comment: My phone is less than two months old, and the charger port looks clean. I tried blowing it out to no effect.